# nodemon : command not found

Tags: macos, npm, homebrew

On Mac, Homebrew to install node

---

Installed nodemon with the following command : `npm i -g nodemon`

But whenever I tried using nodemon it told me : `command not found`

I then tried adding to the $PATH in my ~/.zprofile (I'm using zsh) the following : `/Users/me/npm/lib/node_modules`

which I got from using the command `npm root -g`

Got the following error : `zsh: permission denied: nodemon`

All the other "solutions" involves using SUDO to install a package, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by making sure the folder `npm` was mine with ``` sudo chown -R ``whoami`` npm ```

The correct way was to add `/npm/bin`and not `/npm/lib/node_modules`to the $PATH